# How to Bind menu item with listview

Tags: java, android, listview, kotlin

[image]

Problem - when the user clicks on the menu refresh button(As shown in image) the list of Songs will be Updated(if any change occurs). How to Acheive this(any help is apricated)

Comment: Please add the code where you are loading list of music to the list.

Comment: i am loading/refreshing the Fragment 1 (Music in image) items with this button

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_refresh -> {
                refreshList()
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

private fun refreshList() {
    // Use this method to load the songs just like you might be using the same in OnCreate currently
}
```

Comment: the list is present in the fragment Activity as shown which is not in MainActivity